# Consider, which is part of a question from Sturm-Liouville theory $X''(x) + \lambda X (x) = f (x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider, which is part of a question from Sturm-Liouville theory

$$X''(x) + \lambda X (x) = f (x) $$
$$X(0) = X (L) = 0 $$

I have considered my three cases where $\lambda =0, \lambda < 0, \lambda >0$ and have determined the eigenvalues value to be the following,

$$\lambda _ n = (\frac {n \pi}{L})^2$$  for $n $ greater than $1$.

However my question is how do i get following eigen function which has been normalized,

$$\sqrt {\frac {2}{L}}\sin (\frac {n\pi x}{L})$$

I am a little confused where the $\sqrt {\frac{2}{L}}$ is coming from

Comment: I believe it follows from the fact that $\int_{0}^{L}\psi_{n}\psi_{m}dx=\begin{cases}
1 & ,n=m\\
0 & ,\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the basis functions to be orthonormal, we require $$ \int_0^L {X_n}^2(x) \ dx = 1 $$

So the coefficient has to satisfy

$$ \int_0^L  {A_n}^2 \sin^2 \left( \frac{n\pi}{L}x \right)\ dx = {A_n}^2 \frac{L}{2} = 1 $$

Comment: Thanks for your submission!